# Calculating time to 0?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

**Quick question format**:

Let $a_n$ be the sequence given by the rule: $$a_0=k,a_{n+1}=\alpha a_n−\beta$$

Find a closed form for $a_n$.

**Long question format**:

If I have a starting value $x=100000$ then first multiply $x$ by $i=1.05$, then subtract $e=9000$.  Let's say $y$ is how many times you do it.

Anyone know of a formula to get $e$ given $y,x,i$ and given the total must be $0$ after $y$ "turns"?

Example:

$$y=1: xi-e=0$$

$$y=2: ((xi-e)i-e)=0$$

and so on...

Comment: I strongly suspect that you want to multiply by $1.05$, not by $0.05$.

Comment: Sorry! yes, you are right, fixed.

Comment: Maybe you could try to state the problem in a more compact way to visualize (and probably more appealing to people surfing over this site). "Let $a_n$ be the sequence given by the rule: $$a_0=k,\quad a_{n+1}=\alpha a_n - \beta$$ Find a closed form for $a_n$."

Comment: Done! added what you suggested

Comment: I am sorry I do not know mathematics well but can understand basic formulas.  I am hoping for an answer like e= ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will change notation. Let $A$ be what you call $x$, let $P$ be what you call $e$. Let $i$ be the interest rate, which would in your concrete case be $0.05$, that is, $5\%$. I will leave your $y$ alone, though I am tempted to call it $n$.

Let us calculate, patiently at first.

After $1$ year we have $A(1+i)-P$.

After $2$ years we have $A(1+i)^2-P(1+i)-P$. (We multiplied the previous result by $1+i$, then subtracted $P$.)

After $3$ years we have $A(1+i)^3-P(1+i)^2-P(1+i)-P$.

Calculate a little more, perhaps writing down what we have after $4$ years, and after $5$ years.

You will see that after $y$ years we have
$$A(1+i)^y -P\left( (1+i)^{y-1}+(1+i)^{y-2}+\cdots +1\right).$$

The finite **geometric series** $1+(1+i)+(1+i)^2+\cdots +(1+i)^{y-1}$ has sum $\dfrac{(1+i)^y-1}{i}$.

So setting what we have left after $y$ years equal to $0$, we get
$$P=Ai\frac{(1+i)^y}{(1+i)^y-1}.$$

Comment: I see...so here P is my e right? I will check now thank you.

Comment: Be careful that this formula is valid only if we have exactly $0$ after $y$ years. Very often, we pass directly from a positive value to a negative value. (it is the case in your example)

Comment: Hmmm...yes, you are right...I am checking it with some test values and it is correct, but not exact...but good enough for my use! thanks everyone!!

Comment: It is in fact exact. But your repayment schedule may not be. Tiny-seeming differences in $i$, that you can get by premature rounding, can make a significant difference when $y$ is large.

Comment: With example values: I=0.05, A=100000, y=14 I get P=5102.396945726 which can't possibly be right...? because at ~5000 I would say the starting amount will last easily 20 years+...

is something missing?

Comment: @David19801: Had one my usual typos in the last equation (everything before that is right).

Comment: Critical typo! lol, it now works perfectly! thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Let's $u_0 = x$, and $u_{n+1} = iu_n - e$.

To solve this equation, let's $l= il-e$, and $v_n = u_n - l$.

Then $v_{n+1}= i v_n$ ans $v_n = i^n v_0$, so $u_n = l + i^n v_0 = l + i^n (x - l)$.

But $l = e/(i-1) = 180 000$. So $u_n = 180 000 - 80000*1.05^n$. So $u_n \leq 0$ is equivalent to

$$180 000 - 80000*1.05^n \leq 0$$
$$1.05^n \geq 180000/80000 = 2.25$$
$$n \geq 17$$

(And $u_{17} \neq 0$ !)

**General case** :

Let's $l = e/(i-1)$. If $i > 1$ and $x > l$, $u_n \leq 0$ is equivalent to

$$l + i^n(x-l) \leq 0$$
$$i^n \geq l/(x-l)$$
$$n \geq \frac{log(i)}{log(l) - log(x-l)}$$

So $$y = E(\frac{log(i)}{log(l) - log(x-l)}) + 1$$

Comment: You forgot the -e?

Comment: Yes, ça va le devenir !

Comment: I see, so it will take >=17 iterations to reach 0.  But how to rewrite as e=... ? is it possible?

Comment: You want to mean y=... ?

Comment: I am trying for: given y=something then what is e.  so for example, you know it will be for 99 iterations.  what is e to make the formula 0 after 99 iterations...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've forgotten that. It's impossible, because $y$ is an integer. So if $e'$ is very close to $e$, they will have the same $y$.